# Data scope in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to vue.js I'm working with the code below and run into some problem. I was trying to access data myData within a for loop within a method `myFunction` in the method object using `this.myData` but it is inaccessible/out of scope

```
 export default MyComponent.extend({
    data:function(){
    return {
        myData: []
    }
},
ready:function(){
    this.myFunction();
},
methods:{
    myFunction:function(){
        Vue.http.get('/getdata').then((response) => {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.info.length; i++) {
            this.myData.push(response.data.info[i].address);
        }

    });
    }
}
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, this is a scope issue. Your `then()` function has a different scope. You can `.bind(this)` at the end of your function to pass `this` to the function.

```
Vue.http.get('/getdata').then((response) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.info.length; i++) {
        this.myData.push(response.data.info[i].address);
    }
}.bind(this));
```

Another approach you  may often see is aliasing `this`:

```
var self = this;

Vue.http.get('/getdata').then((response) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.info.length; i++) {
        self.myData.push(response.data.info[i].address);
    }
});
```

Comment: There are some ES2015/ES2016 approaches to consider as well, but I'm not familiar with them. See #4 onwards at https://www.sitepoint.com/bind-javascripts-this-keyword-react/

Comment: You're using arrow functions, `this` should be exactly what you're expecting without the `.bind(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using 'ready' use the new functions of vue 2.0 https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

you can use `mounted () {this.myFunction ()}`

when executing the function you can already see the `data ()` of the component