# Adding an event handler on a javascript instantiated component inside a vue component. (google.maps.DirectionsRenderer)

Tags: google-maps, vue.js

We have a vue app that house a google apps component that uses the Google directions API.
To do this we initiate the map, and make a DirectionsService instance and a DirectionsRenderer instance. We need a function to be called when the route change.

```
methods: {
    initMap() {
      if (this.$refs.baseMap) {
        this.$refs.baseMap.$mapPromise.then(map => {

          this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService

          this.directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
              draggable: true,
              map: map,
            })

          this.directionsRenderer.addListener('directions_changed', 
            function() {
              this.computeTotalDistance()  // I need this to be a called when the direction change
            }
          )
        })
      }
    },
    computeTotalDistance(){
      // do some code
    }
```

the code above does not understand what 'this' is since it is in a addListener function. How do I make it work?

Comment: Duplicate of [Data scope in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39707325/data-scope-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a variable reference to `this` should work:

```
const self = this
this.directionsRenderer.addListener('directions_changed', 
     function() {
         self.computeTotalDistance()  // I need this to be a called when the direction change
      }
)
```